# Python multiprocessing: Reuse a method and avoid instantiation in subprocesses

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to run a function `function` of a class `Foo` in multiple subprocesses created by `multiprocessing.pool` in my main file`Main.py`.

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
from Foo import Foo

f = Foo()

def get(n):
    print f.ID
    sys.stdout.flush() # Print the used instance's ID immediately
    return f.function(n)

def calculate():
    s = pool.map_async(get,range(4))
    return s.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    result = calculate()
    pool.close()
```

The class `Foo`is defined in `Foo.py` like

```
import random

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Initialized!'
        self.ID = random.random() # Assign an unique ID to spot instance
        pass
    def function(self,x):
        return x**2
```

The output I get is (with the ID obviously randomly)

```
Initialized!
Initialized!
0.955181146828
0.955181146828
0.955181146828
0.955181146828
>>> Initialized!
Initialized!
Initialized!
```

I want to avoid that a new instance of `Foo` is created by every subprocess. Why is this happening although all subprocesses then use the same instance as desired?

Notice also that `f = Foo()` cannot be placed after `if __name__ == '__main__':` or else

```
NameError: global name 'f' is not defined
```

Comment: I ran your code as-is, couldn't reproduce the behaviour from terminal (Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit). I also ran your code with the modification of adding the class definition to the main file. That too gave me only one instance of the `Foo` object.

Comment: I guess you're running it on Windows right? This is quite relevant information.

Comment: Yes, I unfortunately am bound to use Windows 7 x64, Python2.7 x32.